# How to get the exact coordinates of the daily maximum in xarray resample function?

Tags: numpy, python-xarray

I have two xarray datasets which are both hourly data over a few years, named `ds_ffdi` and `ds_wdir`. They are identical with the same hourly "time" coordinate.

An example of the datasets are:

```
  import numpy as np
  import pandas as pd
  import xarray as xr

  time = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", freq="H", periods=1461 * 24)
  np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
  ds_ffdi = xr.Dataset({"ffdi": ("time", np.random.rand(1461 * 24)), "time": time})
  ds_wdir = xr.Dataset({"wdir": ("time", np.radians(np.random.randint(low=0, high=359, size=1461 * 24))), "time": time})
```

What I want to achieve is to get max daily value for `ds_ffdi` and find daily value for `ds_wdir` to which hour the max ds_ffdi falls. For example, for the date of 2001-01-01, 13:00 has the max daily value of ds_ffdi; then I want to get the ds_wdir value for the hour of 13:00 and use this value as the daily value for 2001-01-01 for ds_wdir.

I was able to run this:

```
da_ffdi_daily_max = da_ffdi.resample(time="1D").max(dim='time')
```

This gets max daily ds_ffdi value but the time coordinate of which hour this max value occurs is lost. I want to keep the hour and apply it to ds_wdir.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide some example code to work with?

Comment: @Val. I added some example code; hope this makes more sense.